Related Products show Huge Pixelated images
magento is displaying my related products as super enlarged pixelated images, how do I fix this?

Most likely, you configured wrong sizes for the related product images in your custom theme.

Open the template that renders related products list on you product page. For a Luma-based theme it should be something like Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml
Find which image ID is requested for the related products. In default Luma the ID is 'related_products_list'
Open etc/view.xml file in your custom theme and check which size is used for the image ID. If my assumption is right, the size is less than the one you're trying to render on frontend. In this case define correct image size. Something like:
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            ...
            <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
                <width>500</width>
                <height>500</height>
            </image>
            ...
        </images>
    </media>
</view>



